# css 3 column div centered fixed width left middle and right overflow:hidden

Tags: css, web

i want to create a 3 column div layout with left middle right all fixed size and left and right column cutoff if the screen is too small. 
But the contents will always centered with fixed width.
(overflow:hidden with no scroll bar)

```
 left-   width:300px;
 middle- width:1000px;
 right-  width:300px;

If screen fit:
|       width:100%        |
[left][   middle   ][right]

If screen does not fit:
   |    width:100%     |
[left][   middle   ][right]

If screen too large:
|          width:100%            |
   [left][   middle   ][right]

<div style="container">
  <div style="left"></div>
  <div style="middle"></div>
  <div style="right"></div>
</div>
```

What css should i use for each?
I been searching but all i could find is fluid layout which is not what I wanted.

Any help would be appreciated, or point me to the right post.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position the container absolutely if it's of fixed width.

```
.container {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -800px; /* half of the width */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1600px;
}

.container:after { /* clear fix */
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.container > div {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
}

.left, .right {
  background: #369;
  width: 300px;
}

.middle {
  width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: This one works for me, didn't know can margin-left: -800px; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First off the style attribute should be class attribute if you wish to use an external css file. You can try out this simple example. I just added some background color to make the `div` visible:

http://codepen.io/shirofuji/pen/eByYgw

Comment: Yeah, I mean Class, don't know why I put as Style. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want a fixed width and not a responsive one, but:

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1600px;
}
.wrap:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
.left, .middle, .right {
  float: left;
}
.left {
  width: 300px
}
.middle {
  width: 1000px;
}
.right {
  width: 300px;
}
```

You also need a container div.

Answer (score 0):

### CSS

```css
.container { font-size: 0; text-align: center; }
.left, .right, .middle { display: inline-block; height: 500px; }
.left, .right { width: 300px; background: #f3f3f3; }
.middle { width: 1000px; background: #AAA; }

@media (max-width: 1600px){
  .left, .right { display: none; }
}
```

### HTML

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

The `font-size:0` is to ensure there are no spacing between the blocks.